# Aborting an ASP.NET Web Service asynchronous call

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web service which takes quite some time to complete execution, and i am calling this web service asynchronously. I also want to implement an Abort functionality which will abort the web service method. Currently, i am observing that even if I dispose the requesting Web Service object, the web service completes it's execution in the server side anyways. How do i achieve an Abort functionality?

Answer (score 2):

you call the Abort() method on the web service proxy object itself. don't simply dispose of it.